# Management of multiple implementation of interface in Spring

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, dependency-injection

In my Spring application , I have some interfaces and its implementation

```
public interface Validation(){
    boolean validate();
}

public interface ValidationLogicA extend Validation(){

}


public interface ValidationLogicB extend Validation() {

}

public interface ValidationLogicC extend Validation() {

}

public class ValidatorOne implementaion ValidationLogicA, ValidationLogicB {
    boolean validate(){
     // do logic
    };
}

public class ValidatorTwo implementaion ValidationLogicA, ValidationLogicC {
    boolean validate(){
     // do logic
    };
}

public class ValidatorThree implementaion ValidationLogicC {
    boolean validate(){
     // do logic
    };
}
```

So the idea of the above code is that :

- I can inject all of validator of one type (ValidationLogicA, ValidationLogicB, ValidationLogicC), and the validator may be in common and can be reuse (for example ValidatorOne is a logic of both ValidationLogicA and ValidationLogicB)
- In the caller class , just inject all of implementation of validation for example :

```
@Component
public class CallerA {

    private final List<ValidationLogicA> validateOfA;
    
    public boolean doValidate(){
        // do something
    }
}
```

So with the code above, all implementaion of ValidationLogicA , which is ValidatorOne and ValidatorTwo will be inject to do some business logic.
And now if we have new validation logic for example ValidationLogicD, which also have ValidatorOne in its logic, so just modify ValidatorOne and implementing ValidationLogicD:

```
public class ValidatorOne implementaion ValidationLogicA, ValidationLogicB, ValidationLogicD
```

So my question is that , with spring bean, Is possible to manage all of implementation of interface (for example ValidationLogicA) separately, for example in a different class config,
and then in that config class we just add or remove implementation without change concrete class (for example ValidatorOne)

I'm trying to find another solution, which is better and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this solution. To add new validation type you just need to extend enum and implement Validation:

```
public enum ValidationType {
    VALIDATION_A,
    VALIDATION_B,
    VALIDATION_C
}

public interface Validation {
    boolean validate();
    ValidationType getValidationType();
}

public abstract class ValidationLogicA implements Validation {
    public ValidationType getValidationType() {
        return ValidationType.VALIDATION_A;
    }
}

public interface Validator {
    boolean validate();
    Set<ValidationType> getValidationTypes();
}

@Service
public class ValidatorOne implements Validator {
    private static final Set<ValidationType> VALIDATION_TYPES = Set.of(ValidationType.VALIDATION_A, ValidationType.VALIDATION_B);

    @Autowired
    private List<Validation> validations;

    @Override
    public boolean validate() {
        for (Validation validation : getValidations()) {
            if (!validation.validate()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ValidationType> getValidationTypes() {
        return VALIDATION_TYPES;
    }

    private List<Validation> getValidations() {
        return validations.stream()
                .filter(validation -> VALIDATION_TYPES.contains(validation.getValidationType()))
                .toList();
    }
}

@Service
public class CellarA {
    private Set<ValidationType> CELLAR_VALIDATION_TYPES = Set.of(ValidationType.VALIDATION_A, ValidationType.VALIDATION_B);

    @Autowired
    List<Validator> validators;

    public void doValidate() {
        for (Validator validator : getCellarValidators()) {
            // validate
        }
    }

    private List<Validator> getCellarValidators() {
        return validators.stream()
                .filter(validator -> validator.getValidationTypes().stream().anyMatch(CELLAR_VALIDATION_TYPES::contains))
                .toList();
    }
}
```

Comment: So first of all thanks for your answer. But I have a little bit confuse and want to ask to more clarification. As I understand your ValidatorOne.class is similar to my CallerA.class , is this true ? If so then what is the concrete validator class look like , does it need to implement or extend anything ? (Note that as I mention in the question, a concrete validator class may be is a common logic and can be used by many validation logic)

Comment: @Tom added cellar, my idea was to use enum to control what validations and validators to use. I think controlling it will interfaces not so easy to understand. Also it does not allow extension of your Validator, for example if you need ValidatorOne to have 10 Validations, you will have ValidatorOne extend  ValidationLogicA, ValidationLogicB, ValidationLogicC, ValidationLogicD ....